# Who does Lucky call in Lucky (2017)?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, lucky-2017

Lucky calls someone twice in *Lucky* (2017), first to ask, "Is realism a thing?" and the second time to share a personal story. I've never figured out who is on the other side of the phone.

Comment: Welcome to [movies.se] SE! Are you sure you're asking about *Lucky* (2019), and not *Lucky* (2017)? [This article](https://www.leftlion.co.uk/read/2018/september/film-review-lucky) suggests that the "Is realism a thing?" dialogue was in *Lucky* (2017).

Comment: Oh my bad. I've made the required changes. Thanks!